# Javascript: pushing an object into a collection

Tags: javascript

I have a Msg object and a `MsgCollection` object.

Msg object:

```
function Msg(text, timestamp, source, thread_id) {
    Msg.RECEIVED = 1;
    Msg.SENT = 2;

    this.thread_id = thread_id;
    this.text = text;
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
    this.source = source;
}
```

MsgCollection object:

```
function MsgCollection() {
    this.all = [];
}
MsgCollection.prototype.push = function(msg) {
    this.all.push(msg);
    console.log("first message text: " + this.all[0].text);
}
```

In the following code, I take the result object and put all the data into a temporary Msg object before pushing it to a `MsgCollection`:

```
var msgColl = new MsgCollection();
for (var i = 0; i < result.texts.length; i++) {
    var tempMsg = new Msg;
    tempMsg.thread_id = result.texts[i].thread_id;
    tempMsg.text = result.texts[i].message;
    tempMsg.timestamp =  Number(result.texts[i].time_received);
    tempMsg.source = result.texts[i].type;

    msgColl.push(tempMsg);
}
```

Unfortunately, it seems that execution is stopped when I try to print out `this.all[0].text` in the push method. In other words, nothing seems to be getting pushed into the `msgCollection` object. Maybe this is a bit complex, but maybe I can receive some guidance on how to debug?

Thanks

Comment: What does it say in console, when you output `this.all[0]`?

Comment: `var tempMsg = new Msg();`

Comment: @Ilya: Doesn't make a difference afaik...

Comment: seems fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/bjJL9/1/

Comment: any error in the browser console

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var tempMsg = new Msg();
```

and

```
tempMsg.timestamp = new Number(result.texts[i].time_received);
```

works well
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ZykSJ/)

Comment: You're right, everything seems to work. Something else in my code is messing up. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < result.texts.length; i++) {
    var tempMsg = new Msg();
    tempMsg.thread_id = result.texts[i].thread_id;
    tempMsg.text = result.texts[i].message;
    tempMsg.timestamp = new Number(result.texts[i].time_received);
    tempMsg.source = result.texts[i].type;

    msgColl.push(tempMsg);
}
```

And as you asked for 'guidance on how to debug' you can always choose chrome developer's tools else I recommend to go with [firebug](https://getfirebug.com/)

Else for simpler debugging you can do the following as well(You can use a try-catch):

```
try {
   //Your code goes here..
   alert(Obj); //You can Inspect an object here..
}
catch(e) {
    //If any error you will inspect here..
    alert(e); 
}
```

I think this can help you..